# struct and garbage collection

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, value-type

I am checking the memory usage of my service and found out that the private bytes are increasing with time. The service creates the new components it requires and they only get disposed when the service stops. So I am searching for the code which creates new components when there is a service call and trying to dispose them when they are not required. I am using PerfMon to check the private bytes.

So am I on the right track till now?

Moreover, I have found that one of the method creates new struct every time and then its not gets disposed or assigned to null.

```
var structInfo = new MyStruct();
structInfo .StructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(structInfo);
MyClass info = this.BuildStructInfo(structInfo);
return info;
```

**EDIT:**

The method returns the class which gets its values from the struct.

Do I need to dispose the `structInfo`, will it be GC collected if I don't do anything?

Comment: Allocating memory is expensive.  The CLR will hold on to as much memory as the system will give it.  Unless you're getting OOM exceptions, stop worrying about it.

Comment: According to you i need to look at other code instead of worrying about this?

Comment: According to Knuth premature optimization is the root of all evil.  Are you having memory issues other than "hey, by chance I looked at my application's memory usage, and it shouldn't be this high"?  If not, then leave it be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A struct is a value type (like an int for example). It will be automatically be GC'ed if it goes out of scope.

You could sometimes see the memory usage growing and growing, without any memory leak at all: if there is plenty of memory available, your GC won't run that often.

I suggest to use a memory profiler, which can show you why some objects are kept alive. I can recommend [YourKit for .NET profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/.net/profiler/index.jsp), which has a 30-day free trial:

- Start your application through YourKit
- Take a memory snapshot
- Search/browse for your classes you suspect to be leaking
- Select path from GC-root

Answer (score 3):

What I see in your code is that `info` struct is *returned* to the caller. So, from the reader of the question point of view, I would say, only God knows who and how will use it.

Call `Dispose(..)` on the struct if you have some *unmanaged* resources allocated inside, and want to get rid of them esplicitly.

On other hand, if you no more need that `info` memory location, just assign a `null` to it, so `GC` will *possibly* collect it on next trip.

Comment: Thanks.Its not nullable and i can't change that. Updated my question.

Comment: @RaoBHavik: tend do not use it like a global variable, but on some level of nested execution it becomes local/function variable, so as scope exited `GC` wll clean up it, so. If you need something more durable, just use `class` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> The service creates the new components it requires and they only gets disposed whent the service stops

So your service must be holding on to these components somehow. It might be by purpose (e.g. caching) or by accident, only you can know.

> do i need to dispose the structInfo, will it be GC collected if i don't do anything

If `structInfo` is a value type, it is only allocated on the stack and removed if it gets out of scope which seem to be quite small in your snippet. GC is not involved here. Does the type of `structInfo` implement `IDisposable`(*) or some other kind of disposing mechanism?  If it does, call `Dispose` explicitely.

(*) Some special scenarios aside, this is quite a risky business and you need to know very well what you are doing.